# Getting the Container configuration of a Docker image using the registry API

Tags: docker, docker-registry

In a CLI, I can can do `docker inspect --type image {some_image}` and part of the answer is:

```
"ContainerConfig": {
    "Hostname": "4beccaca9c40",
    "Domainname": "",
    "User": "",
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": false,
    "AttachStderr": false,
    "Tty": false,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Env": [
        "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
        "/bin/sh",
        "-c",
        "#(nop) ",
        "CMD [\"/bin/sh\" \"-c\" \"cat /marker\"]"
    ],
    "ArgsEscaped": true,
    "Image": "sha256:111ecb4a6197242745f0d74c2ca4e377cfe4a1686b33160d3a8df3d3d1baea58",
    "Volumes": null,
    "WorkingDir": "",
    "Entrypoint": null,
    "OnBuild": null,
    "Labels": {
        "key1": "LabelValue1-L2",
        "version": "1.2.0"
    }
},
```

The [registry API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-2/) defines an answer type of

> - application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json: Container config JSON

but I cannot relate that to a specific API. When I use it with the `../manifests/..` URL I receive the answer in the default format (`application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+json`)(this also happens if I try to use the "fat manifest" format).

Is this configuration information available somewhere?

The registry is the standard registry image pulled a couple of days ago (says `"Created": "2018-01-10T01:22:39.470942376Z"`)

Comment: Can you say a little more about what you're looking for?  `docker inspect` gives the output from the Docker daemon, but the Registry is what `docker pull` and `docker push` interact with.

Comment: `docker inspect` requires the image to be on the local machine. I want to get the same information while keeping the image in a registry (for instance, to make a web interface to the registry, or determine things about the images in the registry). But I think I got my answer (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

So, what is required is:

- A first call to `https://{registry}/v2/{imageName}/manifests/{tag}` with an `Accept` header set to `application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json`

  This returns a JSON, where `config.mediaType` is set to the content type of the V1 manifest (which is always `application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json` as far as I can tell).
- a second call to `https://{registry}/v2/{imageName}/manifests/{tag}` with an `Accept` header set to the content-type obtained above (same URL, only the `Accept` changes).

  This returns a JSON, where the member `history` is a list, and each member of this list has a single `v1Compatibility` attribute which is a string which can be re-parsed as a JSON.

Comment: That is not true. What you are seeing is the registry falling back to a v1 manifest, which so happens to have all the information already in the config. To get the proper container config, you must take the config's `digest`, and query the `blobs` endpoint, not `manifests`.